# GLU Library not found

Tags: install, python, library

I am trying to install PyFTGL to display fonts in my PyOpenGL project.

When trying to install with the `python setup.py install` command from the downloaded PyFTGL source code folder, I get the following error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lGLU
```

Is GLU not already installed on my mac?

This surprises me because PyOpenGL already works fine, I can do `from OpenGL.GLU import *` without problem.

I am using MacOS 10.10.5

Comment: Which version of MacOS and which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am using MacOS 10.10.5 (I just added this information in my question).
As for the Xcode version, I am not sure. When using `/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version` in the terminal i get `xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`.

Comment: I do not use the Xcode IDE, I write python scripts in a text editor and I run them through the terminal

Comment: I suspect you need Xcode to get the glu library or at least to put it in a place that setup can find. If you use home brew just for python I would also look at using conda for the package management.

Comment: I would like to avoid installing Xcode just for this project: I now have Linux on another machine, so I'll continue the project there. Thanks for the advice about using conda, I find it great.